# Cannot set value for Summernote wysiwyg editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dom, summernote

I am trying to set the value of summernote WYSIWYG editor in an update form. So I am fetching the previous content from DB and trying to assign it to a variable.

But I can't assign it no matter how I try to escape the content. 
**I know the error is due to `$college->overview` containing HTML tags and I cannot properly escape/encode them when I try to assign it to a javascript variable**. I tried using double quotes but I still get the same error.

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Which I know is happening due to `$college->overview` containing HTML tags.

Here is my code:

```
<script> 
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
                  var markupStr = {!! $college->overview !!};
                 $('.overview').summernote('code', markupStr);
        });
</script>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the variables with quotes? `var markupStr = '{!! $college->overview !!}';`

Comment: @linktoahref yes I have. But still the same error

Comment: and what if you try to escape the data `var markupStr = '{{ $college->overview }}';` ? Does it still result in error ?

Comment: @linktoahref Yes I tried almost all the combinations and it still results in the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. 
The trick was to `json_encode` the value.

```
var markupStr = {!! json_encode($college->overview) !!};
```

For those in need, I have also written an in-depth tutorial on [how to use Summernote WYSIWYG editor with Laravel](https://www.kerneldev.com/2018/01/11/using-summernote-wysiwyg-editor-with-laravel/).